# Laravel php artisan migrate connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am running Laravel 5 with PHP 7.0.6. When I run the php artisan update command, I get the following error:

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

This is obviously database related.  This happens on a production machine I have as well as local environment. My site is working in both environments.

Does anyone understand this error? Thanks.

Comment: are the connection credentials correct?

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the PHP-CLI database extension. Your site does work because your server is using the PHP-FPM (where you have the PHP extention of your database installed). But when you run `php artisan migrate` command you are actually executing it on the PHP-CLI.

Comment: thank you for this, very interesting. I will look into it

Comment: Worth noting that the error came from the database, the database extension cannot be the error. You'll want to double check the environment the console commands get executed as instead.